# cant connect to tables to each other in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
PDO::prepare("alter table `orders` add constraint `orders_zid_foreign` foreign key (`zid`) references `users` ()")
```

> /home/ahmed/nodtest/FoodOrderingManagementSystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:452

Comment: Should you not be including the DB facade and using `DB::raw`?

Comment: sorry but can you discuses more  please ?

Answer (score 0):

> You may also access the raw, underlying PDO instance using the getPdo method on a connection instance:

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
```

Thereafter you can run your query.

**Note:** Make sure you include the db facade before you call `DB::` via:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;.
```

**Reading Material**

[Laravel Database](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database)